# Throw exception from invalid parameter handler

Tags: c++, exception

I'm using `VS2015` and I want to throw `errno` from invalid parameter handler so that I can format error message in catch block. My code looks like this:

```
_set_invalid_parameter_handler([](wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*, unsigned int, uintptr_t) {
    throw errno;
});
try
{
    char buffer[2];
    strcpy_s(buffer, "testtest");
}
catch (int e)
{
    //strerror
    perror("catch int");
}
catch (...)
{
    perror("catch ...");
}
```

If I compile in `debug` mode, the code works fine while in `release` mode it crashed. Why it behaves differently?

Comment: @hans You are right. And /Ehs also works though I don't know the exact difference between it and /Ehsc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change a compile option, the optimizer removes exception filters too aggressively in the Release build so your program bombs through terminate() right now.

Ensure you have the Release configuration selected, Project > Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > Enable C++ Exception setting.  Change it from the default of /Ehsc to /Ehs.

The "c" qualifier it the sting here, it allows the optimizer to assume that an `extern "C"` function can never throw a C++ exception.  strcpy_s() is a C function.  Using /Eha fixes it as well, that forces the optimizer to assume nothing at all.  But makes `catch (...)` too dangerous, it will now also catch the really nasty SEH stuff like AV.